# Can we generate an OAuth token to send the data to BLOB via Subscription ID rather than Tenant ID

Tags: azure, http, oauth, blob

I am trying to push some data to Azure Blob Storage using HTTP with OAuth Authentication.

Can I use subscription ID instead of Tenant ID in order to generate the OAuth Token to be used to make the call?

Answer (score 2):

No, because the tenant ID is part of the URL where the token is acquire from.
The token endpoint URL looks like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```